# How do i open new modal after closing an open modal

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I am using bootstrap 3.2.0.
I have a scenario of a modal with 3 buttons. Each button will open a new unique modal. But i want it this way, if i click on any of the 3 buttons, the open modal (the one with the 3 buttons) should dismiss and open the new modal. Not modal over modal.

Comment: Use `setTimeout` to delay the opening of the new modal.

Comment: You can use JS to set the display:none of your previous bar

Comment: @antii Haapala: Setting timeout would not be a good option in my case coz I cant restrict time on the user to select an option for the 3.

Comment: use hide event of first modal to open the next one. Please provide your code as well as a sandbox demo is always helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use BS modal events: `hidden.bs.modal` and handle it using jQuery's [`one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/):

**[EDIT]** (*@cvrebert* suggestion in comment to the answer)

```
// 'next-modal' is one of three buttons inside first modal:
$('.next-modal').click(function () {
    // hide current modal and when it's hidden, open another:
    $('#myModal').one('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
        $('#nextModal').modal('show');
    }).modal('hide');
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tq8gfnvq/)

Comment: Your ordering is wrong. You must use `.one()` to setup the hidden handler **before** you call `.modal('hide')`

Comment: @cvrebert , could you explain why? and post some jsfiddle showing how would you do that?

Comment: Event handlers should be added before the firing of the events they're intended to handle. Common sense, yeah? `hidden.bs.modal` is fired asynchronously, so you have an unnecessary minor race condition in your code. You literally just need to move the `.one(...)` so it comes before the `.modal('hide')`; not worth making a whole jsfiddle just to show that.

Comment: Ahhh, that's what you meant :) Sure, it makes sense. It would be better to register event handler before the event happens (and so it is actually because of a hide animation time). I'm not sure why I thought you want the `modal('hide')` handled with `one()` somehow.